# Dynamically generated button does not load view controller content properly

Tags: xcode, swift2, segue

I have created view controller, created segue and named it in attribute inspector, but when I created a button in second view controller programmatically and add an action to call details view controller, details view controller is showing but all of its control is not showing. e.g. if i add an UITextfield to details view controller, its not showing when run.

in design mode:

[image]

[image]

in code:

[image]

[image]

but after run, textfield is not showing:

[image]

first two pages worked very nice, problem in third page where dynamically button created. 
in third page, when i navigate from menu, textfield is not showing:

[image]

second view controller code:

//

```
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  BMSAppIOS
//
//  Created by Md. Muzahid-ul Islam on 1/31/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 NovoTel Limited. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnImage: UIButton!

    var userName: NSString = ""

    let baseUrl = "http://103.248.13.76/BMSRestService/values/"

    let loginParam = "GetMenuItems?LoginId="


    let picker = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "picker"))

    struct properties {
        static let moods = [
            ["title" : "Change Password          ", "color" : "#8647b7"],
            ["title" : "Sign Out                ", "color": "#4870b7"]
        ]
    }


    @IBAction func btnMenu(sender: UIButton) {

        picker.hidden ? openPicker() : closePicker()


    }


    func btnTouched(sender: UIButton) {

        if(sender.tag  == 0){

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ChPasswordIdentifier", sender: nil)


        }


        /*let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "you clicked menu button", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click to remove alert", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)*/


    }

    func createPicker()
    {
        //picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 200, width: 286, height: 291)
        picker.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 286, height: 291)
        picker.alpha = 0
        picker.hidden = true
        picker.userInteractionEnabled = true

        var offset = 21

        for (index, feeling) in properties.moods.enumerate()
        {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: offset, width: 260, height: 43)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgba: feeling["color"]!), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(feeling["title"], forState: .Normal)
            button.tag = index
            button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

            picker.addSubview(button)

            offset += 44
        }

        view.addSubview(picker)
    }


    func openPicker()
    {
        self.picker.hidden = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
            animations: {
                //self.picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width / 2) - 143), y: 230, width: 286, height: 291)

                self.picker.frame = CGRect(x: 155, y: 50, width: 286, height: 291)
                self.picker.alpha = 1
        })
    }

    func closePicker()
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
            animations: {
                self.picker.frame = CGRect(x: 155, y: 50, width: 286, height: 291)
                self.picker.alpha = 0
            },
            completion: { finished in
                self.picker.hidden = true
            }
        )
    }





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createPicker()

        let restUrl=self.baseUrl + self.loginParam + String(self.userName)

        let restClient = RestClient()
        restClient.getResponse(restUrl) { responseObject, error in
            if responseObject == nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

         if let statusCode: AnyObject = responseObject?.valueForKey("status_code"){
                if statusCode as! NSString == "200"{

                   var x = CGFloat(0)
                    var y = CGFloat(0)
                    var width = CGFloat(300)
                    var height = CGFloat(50)
                    var j = 0

                    if let menuItem = responseObject?.mutableArrayValueForKeyPath("data.MENUITEMHREF") {


                        for var i=0;i<menuItem.count;i++ {
                        print (String(menuItem[i]))
                            let imageName = String(menuItem[i]) + ".png"
                        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
                        let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

                           y = CGFloat(70*j+170)

                            if i == 0 {

                                 x = CGFloat(50)

                                 j = j + 1

                            }
                            else{

                                width = CGFloat(125)

                                if i%2 == 0 {


                                    x = CGFloat(225)
                                    j = j + 1
                                }
                                else{

                                    x = CGFloat(50)


                                }


                            }




                        button.frame = CGRectMake(x , y, width, height)
                        button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)



                        //button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
                        self.view.addSubview(button)

                        }
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Error to retrieve data", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click to remove alert", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
        }


    }





}
```

Third view controller:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit


class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg_main.png")!)


        }


    }
```

Comment: Sometimes main view and its subviews mix up due to same background color, so we cannot identify it. Once add some default text in textfield or some background color to self.view and check it.

Comment: i already add a textfield but textfield is not showing even i tried to add imageview with one image but it not showing

Comment: Have you added any constraints to the textfield ? If not trying adding that.

Comment: i have added constraints, its not showing, same result

Comment: As satish said, Have you added background color for View ?

Comment: yes i have tested, background color is showing but any control upon it like textfield is not showing

Comment: Can u share the view hierarchy and constraints in the screenshot as you shared above ?

Comment: as i see in above screenshot you need to scroll down a bit to check for textfield.  Or just give reference to textfield and set becomeFirstResponder to it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: first two pages worked very nice, problem in third page. I scrolled down and found nothing. I tried in many aspect like take a image  view, set image but i found nothing. would u please try this code and give me some output so that i can try.

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. Show _code_. I can't read the code in these tiny screen shots.

Comment: matt, please check, i posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **installed** for any height. Hope it will work.

[content of view controller attribute settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YwTm.png)

[image]